# Create a 2D pin plot

Tags: graphics

I am trying to do pin plots like those found in OEIS to help with pattern recognition. I came up with a way, but it is nasty. I am not sure how to make it better. I looked at Line, but do not know how to make it shorter than the window of the graph.

Here is my code that works (lines are too far away as well):

```
ListPlot[
  Riffle[
    Riffle[Table[{n, n^1.2}, {n, 1, 10}], Table[{n, 0}, {n, 1, 10}]], 
    Table[{n + 1, 0}, {n, 1, 10}], 3], 
  Joined -> True]`
```

[image: Pin plot of n^1.2]

or

```
ListPlot[
  Riffle[
    Riffle[Table[{n, Cos[n]}, {n, 1, 10}], Table[{n, 0}, {n, 1, 0}]],
    Table[{n + 1, 0}, {n, 1, 10}], 3], 
  Joined -> True]
```

[image: Cos[n]]

Comment: That is nicer, but I am trying to figure out how the axis doesn't get highlighted too.

Comment: That's perfect as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot):

```
DiscretePlot[n^1.2, {n, 10}, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[Cos[n], {n,10}, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe I forgot about that. I haven't used in 4 years though, so that might be why.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPlot[Table[n^1.2, {n, 1, 10}], Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Use `Cos@n` for `n^1.2` to get

[image]